# Show synced folder type with vagrant

Tags: vagrant

Is there a way to show the type of `config.vm.synced_folder` (https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html#type) using a `vagrant` command?

I have access to the host system and the Vagrant VM and wasn't able to find where the setting is displayed. VirtualBox does not seem to show the setting either.

My use case is, that I want to see if a setting change has been applied (Switching from NFS to default).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual box shared folder is only created by Virtual Box, the type will be define when you mount this folder in your OS (depending the OS type etc) virtualbox does not know about this type and vagrant can only do its best to mount it depending the type you specified in the Vagrantfile.

To make sure your setting is applied, you should check the output of `vagrant up`:

- something like below will show a default virtualbox type

  ```
  ==> default: Mounting shared folders...
      default: /vagrant => /Volumes/VM/vagrant/myproject
  ```
- below will show a nfs type

  ```
  ==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
  ==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
  ==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
  ```